# Aplication.properties error when changing format

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=secret

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and It works fine.

But when I try to do it this way:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid
        username: root
        password: secret
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
```

It fails with:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

I assume it is a silly syntax error, but I can't notice where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the YAML syntax, you need to specify it by changing the name of the file from `application.properties` to `application.yml`.

Answer (score -1):

YML is very sensitive. Make sure you:

- Use spaces instead of tabs
- Use the proper extension: `application.yml`

See this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

Comment: That's optional. What matters was the file fomat name, which defines the format.